# Should I set the lens profile option in Lightroom If I already have the lens correction information on my Canon 6D?

Tags: lightroom, canon-6d, lens-correction

I've a 6D with lens profile information for all my lenses.  So when I process pictures from the camera in Lightroom do I need to set the lens profile option?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45632/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-activate-lens-corrections-in-camera-when-also-use-lens-corr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you working with RAW or JPEG?  RAW will not use the in-camera correction but JPEG will.

Comment: I shoot RAW.  I didn't know RAW does not use in-camera correction.

Comment: @Vivek - RAW data is just the values from each sensor.  There isn't even color or pixel information associated yet so there wouldn't be a particularly clean way to apply the correction since it would also impact the way that the colors had to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

If you shoot raw then YES you will need to use the lens profile option in Lightroom.